# Differential equation with shifted argument.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the methods for solving the following class of problems:
$$
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=a f(x-\xi),
$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}=a_1F(x_1-\xi_{11},x_2-\xi_{12})\\
\frac{\partial F(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}=a_2F(x_1-\xi_{21},x_2-\xi_{22})
\end{cases}
$$
and so on, where $a$ and $\xi$ are constants or known functions of $x$?

Comment: The first is known as delay-differential equation, existence theory is rather experimental, numerical algorithms exist for some classes.

Comment: @LutzL On the contrary, the existence theory (especially for these very basic cases) is quite well established. The question is instead about obtaining solutions.

Comment: You say it, the existence theory is on a case-by-case basis instead of a fairly general result in the ODE case.

Comment: @LutzL I regret having to note that it is the opposite: the existence is quite well know and is the same for all equations, while finding explicit solutions is quite different. For details of this basic part of the theory I recommend the best book there is on the subject: Hale's book in the AMS Springer collection (the second edition by Hale and Lunel is considered too heavy, since only the experts may really read it, but they already know the subject...).

Answer (score 0):

The best for the first is to substitute $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ and solve for $\lambda$.

For the second, the theory is largely open ground, although depending on the particular constants you may try $F(x_1,x_2)=e^{\lambda_1 x_1+\lambda_2 x_2}$.